# is it possible to assign all subquery results to a list of subquery objects?

Tags: apex, soql

If i have a query like:

```
SELECT id, (SELECT id FROM Detail_Object__r) 
FROM Master_Object__c 
WHERE id IN: trigger.newmap.keyset()
```

Is it possible to assign the results to a list of type Detail_Object__c directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List<Detail_Object__c> details = [SELECT Id, Name
FROM Detail_Object__c
WHERE Lookup_to_Master__c IN :trigger.new];
```

No need to even extract the Ids into Set with trigger.newMap.keyset(); bind variable should work with collection of sObjects.

Comment: voted to delete my answer, this is more accurate/relevant

Comment: thanks good catch! However my real question is if its possible to collect all of the subquery lists and assign them directly to a list of type detail_object__c

Comment: I've undeleted my answer now, as I'm not sure if its relevant or not :)

Comment: Are you looking for a list of subquery lists or a list of Detail_Object__c? This does return a list of Detail_Object__c if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @philhawthorn - I'm confused too :) Both solutions will work  and produce same amount of records in the list; mine just won't waste script statements on looping, I don't think it can get any simpler.
 Maybe OP is after List<List<Detail_Object__c>> or something? Maybe I had to be more specific,
List<Detail_Object__c> details = [SELECT goes here]; :)

Comment: Sorry, this one does work, and was what I had originally before posting. The problem was the trigger was before not after

Comment: Doesnt this answer need to be updated to reflect the actual solution? As it stands PJC's answer appears more accurate.

Comment: Hi @techtrekker, not sure what do you mean? We've discussed the solution on http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4337/salesforce, turbo2oh had something similar to my query in his code and was wondering if there's a better way. He also deleted his own answer (which might make whole thread now look weird)...

Comment: That makes sense, the other thread was making it seem confusing ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could also iterate over them, after you did your query, this way you will have all the results, regardless of how many master objects.

like so:

```
List<Detail_Object__c> detailObjectList = new List<Detail_Object__c>();
for(Master_Object__c m : masterObjectList)
{
     detailObjectList.addAll(m.Detail_Object__r);
}
```

Comment: This is the correct pattern. there is no way to automatically "get" all subquery children from all parent query records out of a query. It is a loop.

Comment: and always better to code for multiple objects, than just a single one.